# jQuery AJAX POST returned data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to make a simple update of an html table when the user clicks different product quantity. Though being very new to jQuery, i'm having some trouble with the ajax POST method.

Here's what i've got so far:
test-table.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function swapContent(count){
        $(".price-sidebar").html("Put animation here").show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myphpscript.php",
            data: {countVar: count},
            success: function(data){

            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('18');">18</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('48');">48</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('96');">96</a>

    <section class="price-sidebar span8" >                
        <h2>Price Comparison</h2>
        </br>
        <table class="price-data">
            <tr>
                <th class='store-row'><h4>Store</h4></th>
                <th class='price-row'><h4>Price</h4></th>
            </tr>

        <!--insert returned foreach data -->


        </table><!--end price-data-->
    </section><!--end price sidebar-->
</body>
```

myphpscript.php

```
require('C:\wamp\www\Single-Serve-Coffee\includes\database-connect.php'); 
$countVar = $_POST['countVar'];

    function PriceCompare($countVar){

        $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT ProductID, MerchantName, Price, PageURL
        FROM merchants
        WHERE ProductID=677 AND Count=' . $countVar . '
        ORDER BY Price');
        $result = $STH->fetchAll();

        foreach($result as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='store-row'><h5 property='seller'>" . $row['MerchantName'] . "</h5></td>";
            echo "<td class='price-row'><h5 property='price'>$" . $row['Price'] . "</h5></td>";            
            echo "<td><a property='url' target='_blank' href='" . $row['PageURL'] . "' class='btn btn-danger'>GET IT</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</br>";
        }
       }
?>
```

I want the foreach looped data to display on the html page, but i'm not sure how to get it there. I know i'm missing the success function, but I don't know how to write the jQuery to call the PriceCompare() function from my php script.

Comment: Just call PriceCompare() from within the PHP file. Line 3 could be: `PriceCompare($countvar)`

Comment: A better way of doing it would be to have the PHP just return json instead of formatted HTML. Then in the javascript success block, you use `$.each` to iterate over each row in `data`.

Comment: Another thing you really should think about is SQL injection attacks. You need to sanitize and validate the PHP input before putting it in the SQL statement. Otherwise, a user could create a bad POST and get all your data, or even delete your database.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ringo. There isn't anywhere where the user can input anything. I am only outputting MySQL data.

Comment: I called the PriceCompare() method in the PHP file, but it didn't output anything in the html. I feel like i'm missing something.

Comment: The solution below seems right to me. Do the for-loop in the js, not the php. The SQL attack could happen easily. If someone just opened Chrome Inspector or Firebug and typed `swapContent("1; drop table merchants;")` it would delete the merchants table.

Comment: please mark an answer as correct, or explain why you're still having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would be better if you return the variable from php and iterates the result in the success javascript function.

modify the php function and do not iterate the result, return only what fetchAll returns.

within PriceCompare function do the following:

```
 $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT ProductID, MerchantName, Price, PageURL
        FROM merchants
        WHERE ProductID=677 AND Count=' . $countVar . '
        ORDER BY Price');
        $result = $STH->fetchAll();

return $result;
```

within the php call the function in line 3 as follows:

```
$ data = PriceCompare ($ countVar);
```

and then return that json encoded object.

```
echo json_encode ($ data);
```

finally put dataType: 'json', in $. ajax javascript like this:

```
$. ajax ({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: 'json',
             url: "myphpscript.php"
             data: {countVar: count},
             success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);//iterate here the object
             }
         });
```

Comment: I made all those modifications Angelo, but if you want me to delete the foreach loop. How do I return the formatted html with json?

Comment: in the success where I put console.log(data);
you can make a for to get the data and print it

Comment: Now I understand you.
woul be better if you use a framework to handle easier the table.
check this powerfull framework of jquery where you can make cool grids and handle these in the result of ajax.
[link](http://jeasyui.com/documentation)